# tablas intermedias en yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Tengo en mi aplicación de yii2 varias tablas intermedias o tablas que se usan para relacionar otras 2 tablas principales, guardando registros muchos a muchos, como en el caso de cargos-funciones, un cargo puede tener muchas funciones y una misma función pertenecer a varios cargos.  A continuación el diagrama:

[image: tablas]

Al momento de crear el registro no se me hizo mayor problema, pues estoy manteniendo fijo el cargo y a ése cargo ya registrado le voy a asignar varias funciones (multiselect) que también están ya registradas en mi tabla.  El problema es cuando voy a programar el modificar o actualizar el registro ya hecho pues no encuentro la manera de hacer que se seleccionen las funciones en el multiselect, me pueden ayudar? o estoy trabajando mal las relaciones muchos a muchos en el framework, no comprendo si hay alguna forma mas adecuada de trabajar estas relaciones con yii2.
[image: modificando]

En el controller:

```html
public function actionUpdate($cargo_id)
    {
        $model = new CargoFunciones();
        $registros = $model->getListado($cargo_id);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'cargo_id' => $model->cargo_id]);
        }
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model, 
            'registros' => $registros, 
        ]);

    }
```

En el modelo:

```html
public function getListado($id)
    {
        $query = (new \yii\db\Query());
        $query = $query->select('funciones.id as funciones_id ,
                                funciones.nombre as funciones,
                                cargo.nombre as cargo,
                                cargo.id as cargo_id')
                                ->from(['funciones', 'cargo', 'cargo_funciones'])
                                ->where('cargo_funciones.funciones_id = funciones.id and cargo_funciones.cargo_id = cargo.id and cargo.id = '.$id );
        
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $rows = $command->queryAll();
        return $rows;
    }
```

El form para insertar/actualizar

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Functions;
use app\models\Positions;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\PositionFunctions */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

?>

<div class="position-functions-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>




    <?= $form->field($model, 'position_id')->dropDownList(
               ArrayHelper::map(Positions::find()->all(),'id', 'aname'), 
               ['prompt'=>'::Seleccione::'])
               ->label('Cargo');
               
    ?>
    <?php //echo $model->function_id;// print_r(explode(",",$model->function_id));
    $funciones = $model->function_id;
    print_r($funciones);
    ?>

    

      <?php 
echo Select2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'name' => 'funciones',
    'attribute' => 'function_id',
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Functions::find()->all(),'id', 'name'),
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'select',
        'multiple' => true
    ]
])
          
    ?>
    

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de la vista dónde aparece el multiselect?

Comment: @granch agregado